# Wordpress 3.9 custom post type permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When i am upgrading my wordpress up to 3.9 and in admin panel (and on site) changes permalinks for my custom post types
`mysite.com/custom-post-type` - **was**
`mysite.com/archives/custom-post-type` - **now**,
but both of these links still working. Whats wrong?

Comment: Re-Save your Permalink-Settings to flush the rules.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Check your network inspector when your naviagte to `mysite.com/custom-post-type`. Will Wordpress redirect you to `mysite.com/archive/custom-post-type`?

Comment: No redirects, a feeling that setting Permalink set in numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make sure that the problem is in the database Permalink options, switch to one of the standard themes and check the permalinks, perhaps in your topic is worth some of the plug-ins that may be prohibited switching Permalink species (or does not work properly).

Comment: Yes, thank you, when switching to the default theme permalinks stood on option archives. My carelessness!

Answer (score 2):

I have used on my plugins for custom post type bellows code.
It's work properly, you can see this

```
function wptPostRegister() {
    $wptLabels = array(
        'name' => 'WPT Slides',
        'singular_name' => 'WPT Slid',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Slide',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Slide',
        'new_item' => 'New Slide',
        'all_items' => 'All Slides',
        'view_item' => 'View Slide',
        'search_items' => 'Search Slide',
        'not_found' => 'No slides found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No slides found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'WPT Slider'
    );

    $wptCustomPost = array(
        'labels' => $wptLabels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'wptslider'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type('wptpost', $wptCustomPost);
}

add_action('init', 'wptPostRegister');
```

.................
You should also a php file on your theme according to your post type. Such as I have used "wptpost-archive.php"

Comment: i was try this method but... This is not help me. nevertheless, thank you very much!

Comment: did u changes your permalink settings from admin dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, you can also wptpost-sinlge.php with your template  elements for view single page.

Comment: I have create a tutorial site for beginners  http://www.e2soft.com/blog & http://www.e2soft.com/forum